# Help with ordering a Google Sheets =QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function, sorting

I'm trying to add an `ORDER by F` to the following query, but every time I do it returns a syntax error.

**ORIGINAL QUERY (working)**

```
=QUERY(data!A2:Z, "select G, E, F, I, J WHERE A = " & C1, "")
```

**UPDATED QUERY (not working)**

```
=QUERY(data!A2:Z, "select G, E, F, I, J WHERE A = " & C1, " ORDER by F")
```

Comment: @pnuts A is a unique ID# and C1 is a blank cell where the user can type a unique ID#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your syntax is wrong. Both shouldn't be working and they're not working. You just think that the first one is working.

`ORDER by F` will not and does NOT cause the parse error.

There should be no `,` after C1

If C1 is number,

```
=QUERY(data!A2:Z, "select G, E, F, I, J WHERE A = "&C1&" ORDER by F")
```

If C1 is text,

```
 =QUERY(data!A2:Z, "select G, E, F, I, J WHERE A = '"&C1& "' ORDER by F")
```

OR

```
 =QUERY(data!A2:Z, "select G, E, F, I, J WHERE A contains ' "&C1& " ' ORDER by F")
```

Notice the position of `&`,`'` and `"` in different instances.